# R-markdown .Rmd or knitr markdown in Jupyter

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a way to use `.Rmd` files **directly** in Jupyter? In other words, is there a way to get jupyter to render a file like this: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/023-engine-python.Rmd?

I love jupyter, but also like the simplicity of the `.Rmd` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [ipymd](https://github.com/rossant/ipymd), which enables saving notebooks as Markdown documents instead of in Jupyter Notebook format.  I don't know enough about knitr to say if there is feature-by-feature compatibility, but it seems like a good start.

[Notedown](https://github.com/aaren/notedown) is another possibility.

Comment: I've used `ipymd' to convert an `.Rmd` to `.ipynb` and open in Jupyter. But I would like to be able to actually work with and edit `.Rmd` documents in Jupyter.

Comment: Are you saying you want to see the raw `.Rmd` format in the notebook?  I don't know of anything that would let you do that.  If you want to have better compatibility with `.Rmd` files, `ipymd` has some examples of how to add your own format that might give you some help doing that.

Comment: I didn't realize that ipymd actually has instructions for making it the default processor for Jupyter. I haven't figured out yet where the config file they talk about is, but I plan to try it out. It may be what I'm looking form.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [fork of ipymd](https://github.com/grst/ipymd) which allows to open `.Rmd` files directly in jupyter notebook.

As opposed to plain markdown, it also supports storing images in a separate `.nb.html` file.